# Determine the number of n-term sequences of 0s and 1s containing no two consecutive $0$s

Tags: combinatorics, fibonacci-numbers

I am reading a chapter about Fibonacci number and generating function.
And there's a question come up but without solution.

I think about it for quite some time, but still can't come up with a solution.

How can it be related to Fibonacci number??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_k$ be the number of such sequences of length $k$. Call a sequence with no two consecutive $0$'s a **good** sequence.

Now consider the number $a_{n+1}$ of good sequences of length $n+1$. There are two types of good sequence of length $n+1$: (i) The ones that end with $1$; and (ii) The ones that end with $0$.

We can make a good sequence of length $n+1$ and of Type (i) by appending a $1$ to any good sequence of length $n$. This is the only way we can make a good sequence of Type (i) and length $n+1$. So there are $a_n$ of these.

We can make a good sequence of length $n+1$ and of Type (ii) by appending $10$ to a good sequence of length $n-1$. If $n\ge 2$, that's the only way it can be done. So there are $a_{n-1}$ of these.

Thus 
$$a_{n+1}=a_n+a_{n-1}$$
 for any $n\ge 2$.

Now calculate $a_1$ and $a_2$, and you will be able to identify the sequence.

**Remark:** If you wish, you may allow sequences of length $0$. There is $1$ such sequence, and it is good.

Comment: So the ans is $F_{n-1}+ F_{N-2}$?

Comment: It depends how you number the Fib. sequence (not everybody does it the same way). If your definition has $F_0=0$, $F_1=1$, $F_2=1$, and so on, then $a_n=F_{n+2}$.